# Rails 5 - ActionCable - Failed to upgrade to WebSocket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, websocket, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to implement a webSocket on a my Rails 5 application.

Here's my channel:

```
class MessagesChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "messages_#{params[:topic]}"
  end
end
```

In my controller I do:

```
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "messages_#{params[:topic_id]}",
      message: @message.message,
      user: current_user.name
```

And my connection class (using Device also):

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.email
    end

    protected

    def find_verified_user # this checks whether a user is authenticated with devise
      if verified_user = env['warden'].user
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The client is a Nodejs application just to test:

```
module.exports.webSocket = function(topic){
  const WebSocket = require('ws');

  const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000/cable');

  ws.on('open', function open() {
    console.log("on open!!");
  });

  ws.on('message', function incoming(data, flags) {
    console.log("got here!");
    console.log(data);
    console.log(flags);
    // flags.binary will be set if a binary data is received.
    // flags.masked will be set if the data was masked.
  });
};
```

And this is what I  get:

```
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-13 14:25:01 -0300
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-13 14:25:01 -0300
Request origin not allowed:
Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-13 14:25:01 -0300
```

I also dont know how to specify the channel to listen to on the NodeJS client. This would also be helpful

**EDIT 1** - Tried adding the following to **development.rb**

```
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['http://localhost:3000']
```

**EDIT 2** - Also tried adding the channel on the node client like this:

```
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000/cable', `messages_${topic}`);
```

But both attempts didnt work.

**EDIT 3** - Another client test:

```
  ws.on('open', function open() {
    console.log("on open!!");
     ws.send('{"command":"subscribe","identifier":"{\"channel\":\"MessagesChannel\"}"');
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What port is your client running on? you want to allow the client, so if rails is running on localhost 3000 you need to change this to the correct origin url:

```
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['http://localhost:3000']
```

For the sake of development, I would just use regex to allow all origins for the time being:

```
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ /http:\/\/.*/, /https:\/\/.*/ ]
```

Also to test the connection more easily, use this jsfiddle - that eliminates settings up your client for now, to just work out being able to connect:

http://jsfiddle.net/BrilliantLa8s/bxkerzf8/2/

Once you've connected, I would recommend using this library for subscribing to action cable channels from your client, which I assume will be written in JavaScript since you mentioned Node

https://www.npmjs.com/package/actioncable-js

Comment: What an awesome answer! So I've tested. I'm connected. It works. But there's a problem. I'm using nodejs to test it. But I'll have another client using react-native (and it uses WebSockets). So how can I 'subscribe' to a channel using only websockets? Or I have to use another library to make that happen ?

Comment: Another note: https://github.com/mwalsher/actioncable-js/blob/master/dist/action_cable.js uses document . And my node app doesnt run on the browser. :(